# Pig Latin conversion of List of strings yields only first string, Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I wonder if you can help me find an error in my code. I am reading a sentence from a text file to convert to Pig Latin and calling the result "string."

```
    words = string.split() 
    vowels = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u', 'y']
    for word in words:
        position = 0
        while word[position] not in vowels:
            position += 1

        if word[position] in vowels:
            return word[position:] + word[:position] + "ay"
```

Could someone explain why this only converts the first word in the sentence? I thought the for loop would pass through all words in the sentence.

__
Edit 3/12/2016 at 2:46pm

Thanks very much for your help, everyone. I followed the approach closest to Saleem's, and I have the output coming out in one string, as I wish, due to having set an empty string called "answer."

The problem comes with the final word in the string of text I wish to convert, when the first character + "ay" is placed on a new line from the rest. Does anyone know why this happens?

```
words = string.split(" ") 
answer = "" 
for word in words: 
    if word[0] in vowels:
        answer += word + "way" + " "
    else:
        position = 0
        for char in word:
            if char not in vowels:
                position += 1
            else:
                break
        answer += word[position:] + word[:position] + "ay" + " "      
return answer
```

for the string "Last word comes out on a new line." 
it yields something like this:

astLay ordway omescay outway onway away ewnay ine.
lay

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem. Seems like the string you entered contains a newline.

Answer (score 1):

The `for` loop *would* go through each word, but you cut it short with `return ...`  If you go to a party and then return with one box of cookies, you need to go back in order to return with another.  It is the same with a function: to return more than one value, you need to call the function more than one time. You could use `yield` instead and use `list(myfunction(string))` when calling it, but you could also create a list to return at the end:

```
words = string.split() 
vowels = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u', 'y']
answer = []
for word in words:
    position = 0
    while word[position] not in vowels:
        position += 1

    if word[position] in vowels:
        answer.append(word[position:] + word[:position] + "ay")
return answer
```

Answer (score 0):

You are returning out really. Can also shorten to

```
def is_vowel(char):
    return char in ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u', 'y']

def piglatin(sentence):
    words = sentence.split()
    piglatin_words = []
    for word in words:
        index = [is_vowel(ch) for ch in word].index(True)
        piglatin_words.append(word[index:] + word[:index] + 'ay')
    return ' '.join(piglatin_words)

print piglatin('this is my original sentance')
```

Answer (score 0):

You are calling return at end of your procedure which will simply exist loop with only first word. You can achieve your goal even without return. e.g. populate a list with desired result and return list at end.

Here is another way to return iterator using yield keyword. See code snippet below.

```
def process(string):
    words = string.split()
    vowels = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u', 'y']
    for word in words:
        position = 0
        while word[position] not in vowels:
            position += 1

        if word[position] in vowels:
            yield word[position:] + word[:position] + "ay"


# Usage example
data = "Be sure to leave a comment if you can help the user out"
result = process(data)
for w in result:
     print(w)
```

Output:

```
eBay
uresay
otay
eavelay
aay
ommentcay
ifay
youay
ancay
elphay
ethay
useray
outay
```

Comment: Thanks for your help Saleem. (And to anyone else who answered who is reading this, thanks to you as well - I'm not sure where S.O. approves of expressing thanks).

Comment: You are welcome.  This forum help those who put some effort and need little help to solve their programming issues. Please accept answer of any contributor who you think is more in align with your  expectations.

Answer (score 0):

One minor suggestion to using a generator - don't write a function for it, use a class and override __iter__.

Why is better explained [here](http://www.effectivepython.com/2015/01/03/be-defensive-when-iterating-over-arguments/), but in short if you pass the function iterator to something that will also iterate the object, it gets a reference to the original iterator. This causes the iterator to be completely consumed before the first function iterates completely, and you'll get a traceback for StopIteration.

Overriding __iter__ allows us to get a new instance of the iterator, instead of a reference.

```
class Piglatin(object):
    """
    Overrides the __iter__ protocol for yielding a piglatin version
    of each word in a provided sentence.

    By overriding the __iter__ magic method, this iterator becomes consumable
    by multiple layers of function calls.
    """

    def __init__(sentence):
        self.sentence = sentence
        self.vowels = set(['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'y'])

    def __iter__(self):
        for word in self.sentence:
            position = 0
            while word[position] not in vowels:
                position += 1

            if word[position] in vowels:
                yield word[position:] + word[:position] + "ay"
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is a way more efficient answer to the above question. this is my first answer on stack overflow and I am open to any kind of feedback.

```
def navy_code(txt) :

for word in txt.split():

    first = word[0]
    if first in 'aeiouAEIOU' :
        crypt = word + 'ay'
    else :
        crypt = word[1:]+first+'ay'
    yield crypt


result = navy_code("Place the submarine under an allied countrys command if possible")
for answer in result:
 print(answer)
```

OUTPUT:   lacePay hetay ubmarinesay underay anay allieday ountryscay ommandcay ifay ossiblepay

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited short-term help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its long-term value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.